# NSButton rendering issues when displayed over NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsimageview

I have a `NSButton` sibling on top of a `NSImageView`.

Whenever I click the window, there are some rendering issues. It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the white edges are the problem.
Strangely, this problem even persists if I override `drawRect:`.
Nothing gets rendered at all, but whenever I click it, those white edges appear.

Also, when the background-image changes, the button gets redrawn and the edges disappear.

Any idea what might cause this?

---

## EDIT

I found out that this actually happens with every single instance of `NSView`
and it actually clears part of the buffer (you can see the desktop wallpaper):

[image]

---

## EDIT 2

I also just found out that this does not happen if I layer-back the windows content-view.

Comment: check it, if it could solve ur problem http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/11/back-to-mac-12-features-from-ios-i-like.html

Comment: @Immi Hm.. Which one of them specifically? I looked at all of them, I didn't see which one you were referring to.

Comment: so far what u have tried...show us your code snippet

Comment: @Immi Like I said, disabling the entire `NSButtonCell` by overriding `drawRect:` still gives me the same behaviour. I wouldn't know what else can possibly cause this issue.

Comment: @Immi There is no code snippet, this happens even for a standard `NSButton`.

Comment: i have never faced such type of prob... i'll suggest u to look carefully at apple docs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47486/discussion-between-immi-and-nsaddict)

Comment: @NSAddict hi buddy...

Comment: Is the button a subview of the image view of just place above. I have had some strange things happen adding subviews to NSImageView so don't do that.

Comment: @boyfarrell It's a sibling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this question was impossible for anyone to answer.

My window had a custom `contentView`, which was just drawing a view with rounded corners.
Instead of using `self.bounds`, I used `dirtyRect` to draw the background.

So when the `contentView` wanted to redraw the background of the controls that were updated, those rounded corners were cut out.